Find marginal pdf of $Y$

If $X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\mu)$ and $Y \mid X \sim U(X-0.5,X+0.5)$ and $-0.5<y<\infty$, find marginal pdf of $Y$.

I get that we need to find $f(x,y)$ by multiplying $f(y\mid x)\cdot f(x)$. Do you sum from $x=0$ to infinity? Is $x-0.5 < y < x + 0.5$ needed at all?

In regards to your (now deleted) comment/answer, as far as I can tell, you cannot solve this problem using the usual methods you describe. You don’t really need to understand the lebesgue differentiation theorem; you just need to use the fact that the pdf of $Y$ is the derivative of the cdf of $Y$ (when the pdf exists) to conclude that $f_Y(y)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{P(y-\epsilon<Y<y+\epsilon)}{2\epsilon}$.

@MikeEarnest Isn't $g(y\mid x):={\bf1}_{x-1/2< y\le x+1/2}$ a valid conditional p.d.f. for $Y$ given $X=x$, such that $g(y\mid x)P(X=x)$ is a joint density in the sense of Radon-Nikodym? (I'm looking at this old posting.) This gives your answer directly by summing that product according to the law of total probability.

@r.e.s. I agree with your comment. I thought that the method you were suggesting would not make sense to OP, since it is not taught in most introductory probability classes/books.

You say we need to find $f(x,y)$. Note that the pair $(X,Y)$ is not jointly continuous, because with probability $1$, the $x$-coordinate of $(X,Y)$ is an integer, meaning $(X,Y)$ is supported on a zero set with measure zero (the union of all vertical lines with integer $x$-intercepts). Therefore, $(X,Y)$ does not have a joint pdf, so you cannot use the usual $f(x,y)=f(y\mid x)f(x)$ method.

I now suggest a different method. Whenever a variable $Y$ has a pdf $f_Y(y)$, then for almost all $y\in \mathbb R$, you can say that
$$\newcommand\e{\varepsilon}
f_Y(y)=\lim_{\e\to 0} \frac{P(y-\e<Y<y+\e)}{2\e}
$$
This is essentially the Lebesgue differentiation theorem in one dimension. With this formula for $f_y(Y)$, we can compute the pdf of $Y$.
Next, you can apply the total law of probabiliy to break up the event $P(y-\e<Y<y+\e)$ based on the value of $X$.
$$
P(y-\e<Y<y+\e)=\sum_{x=0}^\infty P(y-\e<Y<y+\e\mid X=x)P(X=x)
$$
You know that $P(X=x)=e^{-\mu}\mu^x/x!$. You just need to compute $P(y-\e<Y<y+\e\mid X=x)$. Since $Y\sim \text{Unif}(X-0.5,X+0.5)$, as long as $\e$ is small enough, you can say that $P(y-\e<Y<y+\e\mid X=x)$ is equal to $2\e$ if $|y-x|< 0.5$, and that $P(y-\e<Y<y+\e\mid X=x)$ is zero if $|y-x|>0.5$. Therefore, the above infinite summation has exactly one nonzero term. Letting, for $z\in \mathbb R$, $[z]$ denote the nearest integer to $z$, only the $x=[y]$ term is nonzero.
Putting this altogether, we get our final answer for pdf of $Y$:
$$
f_Y(y)=\lim_{\e\to 0} \frac{P(y-\e<Y<y+\e)}{2\e}=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{(2\epsilon)\times e^{-\mu}\cdot \mu^{[y]}/[y]!}{2\epsilon}=e^{-\mu}\cdot \frac{\mu^{[y]}}{[y]!}.
$$
